# How can I compare drone-captured lineament data to dip and strike measurements from field mapping?

Tags: correlation

I have two data sets of discontinuity data, 1) discontinuity orientations measured during field mapping and 2) remotely sensed discontinuities acquired using drone imagery. The drone survey covered larger areas and areas inaccessible on foot. Is there a statistical method I can utilise to compare the data and determine if there is a correlation between the remotely sensed data and the field mapping data? To effectively communicate the results to the interested party, it will be essential to provide a confidence level in the correlation or lack thereof between the two data sets.

Data Set 1 (field mapping discontinuity data): this data set includes the recorded orientation of 2500 joints across the project site. A single entry of this data set includes the XYZ coordinates and dip, dip direction and strike measurements for the respective joint. Data Set 2 (lineament analysis): this data set is the discontinuity data that was extracted from the drone imagery thus it also provides XYZ, dip and azimuth for discontinuities. However, the data comes from drone images which cover the entire project site and not only the areas accessible by foot thus the data have >10 000 data entries.
That being said, my task is to determine whether the dip and azimuth (strike) of discontinuities from the lineament analysis (Data Set 2) correlate with the dip and strike for the discontinuities measured in the field (Data Set 1). I can visually do this on a stereonet plot but I would like to determine a correlation coefficient between the two data sets. This would indicate how relatable the lineman analyses are and whether we can use the data going forward.

I looked at the Pearson Correlation Coefficient but that works with only one parameter, for example comparing azimuth with azimuth which then ignores the dip of the discontinuities. I get good results but the dip of discontinuity is a critical factor which I can’t ignore for stability purposes of the project. So I need a method where I can compare azimuth and dip (Data Set 1) with azimuth and dip (Data Set 2).

I would appreciate any suggestions.
Kind regards,
Marthinus